# How to request this in phpcurl

Tags: php, php-curl

```
$url = "http://ups.youku.com/ups/get.json?vid=XMTQ4ODM5Mjk2MA==&ct=10&ccode=0502&client_ip=0.0.0.0&utid=Ga3jEdWulXoCAXZwOs6IYOEY&client_ts=1501211617"
```

I try to request this by postman,add a header( Referer: http://static.youku.com/ ), it works.

But when I use CURL,it always show me nothing.I am not sure if cookies affect on this because I clear all the cookies on chrome,the postman still works.

I can't get useful cookies for this request by `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`,any body help me pls,thanks.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$headers = array(
    'Referer'    => 'http://static.youku.com/'
);

$url = 'http://ups.youku.com/ups/get.json?vid=XMTQ4ODM5Mjk2MA==&ct=10&ccode=0502&client_ip=0.0.0.0&utid=Ga3jEdWulXoCAXZwOs6IYOEY&client_ts=1501211617';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


?>
```

Comment: check if curl is enabled in your server? Check php.ini file for this

Comment: what is the value of $data ?

Comment: @ParthGoswami Curl is enabled.

Comment: @DhavalChheda When I add cookies in curl,print_r($data) is same to the result that I close the interceptor of the postman.Like this ""data":{"error":{"note":"without authorization,201","code":-6004}}"

Answer (score 0):

Thks for all,try to add params of postman into curl,this way works.

```
$curl = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
CURLOPT_URL => "http://ups.youku.com/ups/get.json?vid=XMTQ4ODM5Mjk2MA%3D%3D&ct=10&ccode=0502&client_ip=0.0.0.0&utid=Ga3jEdWulXoCAXZwOs6IYOEY&client_ts=1501211617", 
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30, 
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET", 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( 
"cache-control: no-cache", 
"postman-token: 88976d57-03fd-7950-6c65-9d0f191010dc", 
"referer: http://static.youku.com/"; 
), 
)); 

$response = curl_exec($curl); 
$err = curl_error($curl); 

curl_close($curl); 

if ($err) { 
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err; 
} else { 
echo $response; 
}
```